# Entering command-line configuration settings in IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to enter the following configuration in IntelliJ:

```
-D something=foo 
-cp /path/one:path/two  
-my_class 
-arg1 
-arg2
```

Where and **how** exactly do I enter this information in the configuration menu below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: the screenshot]

You can run the below test code for the configuration in the screenshot

```
package com.zen.samples;


public class IntellijTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Arg 1 is " + args[0]);
    System.out.println("Arg 1 is " + args[1]);

    System.out.println("System argument is " + System.getProperty("site"));

    System.out.println("Classpath is " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
}
}
```

will give the foll. output to the console

> Arg 1 is arg1
>
> Arg 1 is arg2
>
> System argument is stackoverflow
>
> Classpath is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/zen/IdeaProjects/code/out/production/samples:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/Users/zen/Downloads/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/ant-1.8.4.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/asm-all-4.0.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-base-services-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-cli-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-core-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-docs-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-launcher-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-messaging-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-native-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-open-api-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-tooling-api-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-ui-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-wrapper-1.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/ivy-2.2.0.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jansi-1.2.1.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jarjar-1.3.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jaxen-1.1.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jna-posix-1.0.3.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jsch-0.1.46.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/kryo-2.20.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/logback-core-1.0.9.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-osx-universal-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.3-rc-2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/Users/zen/programs/gradle-1.6/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar

Process finished with exit code 0